# Excel: Creating sets or string of data within single cell

Tags: excel

I've come across a few solutions, but I was wondering if this is just excel's limitation or is there no means to create multiple values to be assesses from the same cell. C3 creates average from all values in neighboring cell.

I'll explain why I wanted to do this. I'm working on a speadsheet for prices of items in a game and want to create a pseudo database out of one of the column's cells. An example of what I was thinking of doing it just simply have in one cell:

2, 40, 300, 200, 340

There's no such thing as C2 (cell name) sum all entries divided by total number of entry? An average of all the values separated by commas?

I know this is easily done with multiple cell, but I wanted to reduce the horizontal clutter, so was wondering if there's ANY way to seperate the values with the syntax, without using VBA or overcomplicated codes.

Comment: So you have cell `C2` that has the values `2, 40, 300, 200, 340` in it, and you want to get the average of those numbers? If you have those in separate cells, why not just use `=Concatenate()` with some delimiter, or `TextJoin()` if you have the newest version, and store that in its own cell. Therefore, you have the range of cells which you can easily do functions with, and a final "helper cell" that stores the numbers all together?

Comment: You are simply trying to use Excel in a way Excel was not meant to be used. It makes no sense, given how formulas work in Excel, to try to store data in one column like you propose AND try to make calculations off of them. If VBA were an option, this would be pretty easy.

Comment: without using VBA you can store the number with "+" 2+40+300 etc. and then EVALUATE the cell using this method http://www.myonlinetraininghub.com/excel-factor-12-secret-evaluate-function then divide the result by (LEN(A2)-LEN(SUBSTITUTE(A2,"+",""))+1) number of + signs plus 1. @Kyle Doesn't everyone try to use Excel in ways it was never meant to be used ;)

Comment: @Gordon, yes, good point. Typically it doesn't occur when the problem at hand is exactly what Excel was built for, and the only reason it's difficult is because you just don't feel like using it the way it was designed to be used.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

the formula is a bear but:

```
=SUMPRODUCT(--MID(SUBSTITUTE(C2,",",REPT(" ",99)),(ROW(INDIRECT("1:" & LEN(C2)-LEN(SUBSTITUTE(C2,",",""))+1))-1)*99+1,99))/(LEN(C2)-LEN(SUBSTITUTE(C2,",",""))+1)
```

[image]

There is a lot happening here, so let's break it down:

`LEN(C2)-LEN(SUBSTITUTE(C2,",",""))+1`: Gets the count of items separated by `,`, In this case `5`.  It is used twice in this formula.  The second is the denominator to get the average.

The second is used in the `(ROW(INDIRECT("1:" & LEN(C2)-LEN(SUBSTITUTE(C2,",",""))+1))-1)`.  Here is the part that iterates.  SUMPRODUCT Will cause a iterations and sum the parts.

The row will return 1,2,3,... to what is returned by the LEN(...) - LEN(...) function.  We subtract one to start at 0.

Each iteration is multiplied by 99 and we add one because MID does not like 0 as the start.

The `SUBSTITUTE(C2,",",REPT(" ",99))` creates a string that has 99 spaces in place of every ",".

The MID takes this string of number separated by now 100 spaces and parses it.  The second criterion is iterating from 1,100,199,298,... and so forth the number of numbers in the cell times.  Which will always fall on a space, since we gave it a 100 spaces in which to land.

The third criterion sets the length of the string to return on each iteration.  We use 99 because again it will always hit a space after the number.

The `--` in front of the MID will cause the returned parsed string to revert to a number.  This forces Excel to drop the extra spaces and see only the number.

It is this number that SUMPRODUCT() maintains and adds to the total each iteration.

Comment: A beautiful bear.

Comment: Absolutely agree.

Comment: You, sir, are a true master. Impressive to say the least.

Comment: Would you be able to explain what's happening here for those less gifted than yourself? I partially understand whats happening, but not entirely.

Comment: Thank you very much @ScottCraner!

Comment: Simply amazing! Thanks a whole bunch. I'm going to try this little trick out! 99 thank yous!

Comment: @DonaldClark-Charest if it works please mark as correct by clicking the check mark by the answer.

Comment: New here. Thanks, will do.

Answer (score 0):

You could also write a VBA function for your issue:

Example:

[image]

Code to be pasted before the function can be used:

```
Public Function AverageCell(allItems As String) As Variant

Dim itemArray() As String
Dim totalsum As Variant
Dim totalav As Long

totalsum = 0
totalav = 0

itemArray() = Split(allItems, ",")

    For Each num In itemArray()
        totalsum = totalsum + num
        totalav = totalav + 1
    Next num

AverageCell = totalsum / totalav

End Function
```